# Integrate a php code in an html file

Tags: php, html, cordova

I want to integrate a php code into my application phoneGap(HTML). So, I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Integrated with HTML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php echo "things"; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please i need your help, Thanks.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a valid error message

Comment: I don't have any error message, but the navigator don't interprete the simple code php

Comment: -1 regarding "doesn't work" is not helpful info in order to support you properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't integrate a php code in an html file
You can integrate HTML code in a PHP file

Comment: I tried that but not work<?php 
$titre='eeeeeeeeeee'; 
?> 
<HTML>  
<BODY LANG="FR"> 
<?PHP ECHO $titre; ?> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>

Comment: How can i integrate HTML code in a PHP file please?

Comment: @Bouaziz — As you did in your question. You just have to run it through a PHP interpretor.

Answer (score 1):

the point is that PHP is a server side language therefore will not run (ie be interpreted) by the mobile device. You need to code in HTML, PHP may be used only if it sits on a server and is part of webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Phone gap is based in navigator tech so you only can use realted technologies like HTML,CSS, Javascript... and php is server based so you can't use it with phone gap.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use PhoneGap with PHP? Which mobile OS has a PHP interpreter build in?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution :)

including php code in ".html" or ".htm" is not work

but

including html code in ".php" file is work

below is your code

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Integrated with HTML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php echo "things now work :) "; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

now let me explain you a short an simple way close this file if its open and than simple rename its extension to ".php" from ".html" or ".htm"

***Thanks***